# Swift 3.0 get dictionary from Xml

Tags: xml, swift, parsing, dictionary, swift3

I can not find a solution to my problem, it's driving me crazy :

For my new project I've to get a dictionary from **xml**, any solution?

Until now I only can get string from **xml** by specific library and i can get an element using its index, in this way :

```
func xmlParsing ()
{

    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml")

    let string = "<a><note><to>Tove</to><from>Jani</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body></note></a>"

    //Parsing from url
    let parserFromUrl = CXMLParser(contentsOfURL: url)

    //Parsing from String
    let parserFromString = CXMLParser (string: string)
    _ = parserFromString!["note"]
    //È possibile effettuare il parsing anche da data 
    //let parser: CXMLParser! = CXMLParser(data: ...) 

    let toveString = parserFromString!["to"].stringValue
    print(toveString)

    let toveURL = parserFromUrl!["to"].stringValue
    print(toveURL)

}
```

Comment: `NSXMLParser` doesn't work? What prints `toveString`? `toveURL`? Try parserFromString!["note"] ? parserFromString!["a"] ?  parserFromString!["a"]["note"]["to"] ?

Comment: this is CheatyXml, the once completely implemented in swift 3 -.-
no,NSXMLParser is not completely implemented in swift 3, so i can't get a dictionary from xml. 
Both print "tove".

Comment: I read a little about CheatyXml, and it seems that `parserFromString!["a"]["note"]["to"] ` should work. NSXMLParser is not completely implemented in Swift 3 ? Really an Apple's object like this one isn't ?

Comment: yes     `parserFromString!["a"]["note"]["to"]` works

Comment: It works? Great then. That's explain on their doc: https://cocoapods.org/pods/CheatyXML But you have to understand the structure or your XML to apply it.

Comment: Yes, but i didn't say that it doesn't work, but it isn't what i'm searching.
I need something for parse **xml** to a dictionary of my objects

Comment: You may have to do the parsing yourself. Create a dictionary, and populate it.

Comment: yes but the xml that i will receive it's big, so i can't get each element by index

Comment: `let myDict = parser.rootElement.attributes.dictionary`?

Comment: it could be perfect, on cocoapods it says that it should work but it's not true unfortunately, in fact if i print `myDict.count` it returns `0`